# ViewForZoomingInScrollView in MonoTouch

Tags: c#, ios, uiscrollview, xamarin.ios, zooming

I am trying to implement a `ViewForZoomingInScrollView` using MonoTouch.
The user takes a picture and the image is added using the code below

```
scrollView.AddSubview (imageView);
scrollView.MinimumZoomScale = 1.0f;
scrollView.MaximumZoomScale = 3.0f;
scrollView.MultipleTouchEnabled = true;
scrollView.ViewForZoomingInScrollView = delegate(UIScrollView scrollView2) 
{
        return imageView;           
};
```

If I swipe a finger across the window I can go from image to image without a problem.
When I try to pinch an image the image moves to the right and I have white space.

Question:

When you pinch the images what steps do you need take in code to re-size and display the enlarged image in the center of the image view?

Answer (score 1):

There are many Xamarin's [samples](https://github.com/xamarin/monotouch-samples) that show how to use `ViewForZoomingInScrollView`. You can get them all from [github](https://github.com/xamarin/monotouch-samples) or you can browser them from the [sample web site](http://samples.xamarin.com/iOS).

This includes the [ZoomingPdfViewer](https://github.com/xamarin/monotouch-samples/tree/master/ZoomingPdfViewer) (a port of Apple's Objective-C sample of the same name). See [Souce Code](https://github.com/xamarin/monotouch-samples/blob/master/ZoomingPdfViewer/PdfScrollView.cs#L82).